# Is the concept of work only defined in mechanics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, energy, work, dimensional-analysis

I'm studying energy and work, so far it looks like [work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_%28physics%29) only makes sense in kinematics (objects that move), but energy makes sense in many other ways (electric, thermodynamic, mechanic).

Is work a concept only applicable on mechanics? If it is then why is it used to define energy? can energy be defined without talking about work?

Does work in Joules only makes sense when the Joule is defined as $N*m$ as opposed to, for example, $C*V$?

Comment: Hi. I would say that it is more easy conceptually to approach the subject. But energy can be defined in other way. In particular, energy you may hear is, as an operator, the generator on time translation, or that it is connected with the Hamiltonian in Hamiltonian mechanics. But, as for kinetic energy, we always assume that something is moving, thus acquiring kinetic energy, by taking that energy from somewhere else. That is, work is done on the object.

Comment: Hi, 
I dont quite understand what you mean, do i need to understand Hamiltonian mechanics in order to really understand what is going on and have a full view of energy as a whole?

Comment: No, I don't mean exactly that, but note that the concept of energy is not as simple as talking about work. I don' t think it' s correct to state "really understand energy". What is the energy of the gravitational field for example? Does energy always gets connected with something moving, then what is the energy of the fields, and so on. On the Hamiltonian mechanics part, what I mean is that one can show there exists a conservative current associated with a conservation law. The quantity that is conserved via time translations is the energy of the system.

Answer (score 0):

In kinematics one describes and analyzes trajectories, but not their connection to other physical processes. There is no force in kinematics.

The concept of work uses the concept of force, so it does not belong to kinematics. It belongs to dynamics, a study of origins of changes in the motion.

> if it is then why is it used to define energy? can energy be defined without talking about work?

There are several concepts of 'energy', even in physics, but the dominant meaning and one that is most important in physics is always based on the concept of work. Kinetic, potential, internal energy are all of this kind.

Answer (score 0):

Joule, in his famous experiments, demonstrated the one-to-one relationship between mechanical work and internal energy change.  Later, others demonstrated the equivalence between these and electrical work (and other forms of energy).

Answer (score 0):

Yes Energy can be defined without reference to work. In the context of more advanced physics like [Lagrangian mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics), There's [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem); It states that for every symmetry that's present in our laws of physics, there exists a conserved quantity(does not change with time) that is associated with this symmetry. For example, if the laws of physics does not depend on your position on space, there exists a quantity(linear momentum) that is conserved. When our laws of physics does not change with time(exhibiting time-translational symmetry), there exists a quantity that's conserved, this quantity we call energy. This is the most accurate definition you'll find for energy.

Regarding $\text{CV}$ where I suppose you mean $\text{Coulomb}$ $\text{Volt}$, you'll notice from dimensional analysis that this has the same units as that of $\text{Joule}$ : $$\text{CV= C}  \dfrac{\text{Nm}}{\text{C}}\text {=Nm}$$.

And it's a valid relation, this is units of electrical potential energy.

Answer (score 0):

Work, by its definition, is by mechanical. Potential energy and kinetic energy can be converted from work. We also talk, for example, heat using energy, which seems has nothing to do with either potential energy or kinetic energy. But later, you will find in statistic mechanics, heat is related to the kinetic energy of particles. But it is too expensive to use molecular kinetic energy for heat calculation. Thus we use energy in general.